# What is the difference between a Technical Report and a Technical Specification?

Tags: c++, terminology

The terms *Technical Specification* and *Technical Report* are used seemingly interchangably when talking about upcoming C++ features (e.g. here or cppreference.com), however I could not find any meaninful distinction or definition of the terms. What is the difference if there even is one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [The different types of ISO publications](https://www.iso.org/deliverables-all.html):

> **International Standards**
>
> An International Standard provides rules, guidelines or characteristics for activities or for their results, aimed at achieving the optimum degree of order in a given context. It can take many forms. Apart from product standards, other examples include: test methods, codes of practice, guideline standards and management systems standards.
>
> **Technical Specification**
>
> A Technical Specification addresses work still under technical development, or where it is believed that there will be a future, but not immediate, possibility of agreement on an International Standard. A Technical Specification is published for immediate use, but it also provides a means to obtain feedback. The aim is that it will eventually be transformed and republished as an International Standard.
>
> **Technical Report**
>
> A Technical Report contains information of a different kind from that of the previous two publications. It may include data obtained from a survey, for example, or from an informative report, or information of the perceived “state of the art”.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that I overlooked a sentence on cppreference.com about [Experimental C++ Features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental):

> Note: until 2012, these publications used the TR (technical report) format. Since 2012 ISO procedure changed to use the TS (technical specification) format.

So while [@Bob_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425) provided information on the definitions, this is what it means for C++ programmers: There is no difference.